# Spring Boot Service unrecognized

Tags: ubuntu, spring-boot

I build my spring-boot application with version Spring Boot 1.4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 and using executable build option. The final jar file is ok to run as a single executable.

I try to use following command 
`ln -s xxxx.jar /etc/init.d/coachService` 
to  create a service.

When I try to start service using service coachService start, it tells me "unrecognized service".

I checked the jar permission , it has execute permission.

Please tell me what's going wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html) says, you should have your application installed in `/var/myApp`

> Assuming that you have a Spring Boot application installed in /var/myapp, to install a Spring Boot application as an init.d service simply create a symlink:
>
> `$ sudo ln -s /var/myapp/myapp.jar /etc/init.d/myapp`
>
> Once installed, you can start and stop the service in the usual way.
>   For example, on a Debian based system:
>
> ```
> $ service myapp start
> ```

Just install the application in the right place and rename `myapp` with your appname and service.

Comment: @Lopakhin its because spring made it as a standard. And all the linux folders has a meaning. [Look here](http://serverfault.com/a/24525)

Answer (score 2):

I found solution that give permission for file jar before do follow of guide spring.
You run command line:

> sudo chmod +x myapp.jar

Then run

> $ sudo ln -s /var/myapp/myapp.jar /etc/init.d/myapp
>
> $ service myapp start

This solution I found [here](http://ealchemy.com/spring-boot-unrecognized-service/)

Hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. As far as I can see it has nothing to do with where the jar file is situated, but it has to be executable. That solved the problem for me.
The newer [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-service) of spring reads

> Assuming that you have a Spring Boot application installed in
>   /var/myapp

this I understand as the listing of an example, not a rule. My applications live under /opt/application and not in /var.